# JavaScript узнать размер enum

Tags: javascript, enum

Есть массив ключ-значение.

```
var enumKeys = {1:3,2:20,3:10,4:10};
```

В цикле сравниваю значения элементов. Нужно указать первый и последний (т.е. размер enumKeys) элементы.

```
for (var i = 2; i < enumKeys.lenght; i++) { 
    // ...
}
```

`enumKeys.lenght` дает значение `undefined`
Как узнать размер `enumKeys.lenght`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var enumKeys = {1:3,2:20,3:10,4:10};
console.log( Object.keys( enumKeys ).length );

Object.keys( enumKeys ).forEach( propName => console.log( enumKeys[ propName ] ) );
```

Comment: СпасиБо! Хороший ответ!